# Angular2 http.get code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am trying out this code in Angular2 beta 15.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h2>Basic Request</h2>
      <button type="button" (click)="makeRequest()">Make Request</button>
      <div *ngIf="loading">loading...</div>
      <pre>{{data.title}}</pre>

    `

})
export class AppComponent {

    data: any;
    loading: boolean;

    constructor(public http: Http) {
    }
    makeRequest(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.data = res;
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }

}
```

For some reason it's getting the data but not displaying it.

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: does your `loading` property get updated properly?

Comment: It just says Loading... and the response is null

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My code works fine on  `"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15"` :

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS,Http,Response} from 'angular2/http';
// see issue more detail here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632#issuecomment-167026172
import 'rxjs/Rx';



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
      <h2>Basic Requests</h2>
      <button type="button" (click)="makeRequest()">Make Request</button>
      <div *ngIf="loading">loading......</div>
      <pre>title : {{array.title}}</pre>

    `,
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS]
}
export class AppComponent {

    array = Array<any>;
    loading: boolean;

    constructor(
        public http:Http
    ){

    }
    makeRequest(): void {
        this.loading = true;
        this.http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos/1')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {
                this.array = res;
                this.loading = false;
            });

    }

}
```

- Import `import 'rxjs/Rx'` see issue more detail here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5632#issuecomment-167026172
- Import `import 'HTTP_PROVIDERS'`
- Add providers: `[HTTP_PROVIDERS]`

Comment: It works. How can i catch http request error ? like request error code too.

Comment: You can do a .catch(err => console.log("here is my error", err)) after the subscribe.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks ok, just change to:

```
{{data?.title}}
```

`data` is undefined until your request completes. elvis operator helps to avoid null pointer.

Also add missing import:

```
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Comment: Getting response null ...no data coming in